# Buscar CADENA con MAYOR número de MINÚSCULAS +Recursividad +Java

Tags: java, recursión

El enunciado completo es: 
"*Dada una lista de String buscar la cadena que tiene un mayor número de caracteres en minúscula. Implementar una solución RECURSIVA lineal final en JAVA*"

Os dejo lo que llevo hecho y el error que me da al ejecutarlo, a ver si alguien me puede echar un cable...
Error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3"

```
public static void main(String[]args) {

    List<String>lista = Arrays.asList("Universidad", "Empresa", "Startup");
    System.out.println("La cadena con mayor numero de minusculas es: " +cadMayor(lista, lista.size(), cuentaMinusculas(lista.get(lista.size())), lista.size()-1 ));

}

public static String cadMayor(List<String>lista, int tamLista, int cuentaMinusculas, int pos) {

    String res = "";
    int comparador;

    if(tamLista == 1) {
        res = lista.get(pos);
    }else {
        comparador = lista.get(pos).compareTo(cadMayor(lista, tamLista, cuentaMinusculas(lista.get(pos)), pos-1));
        if(comparador <= 0) {
            res = lista.get(pos);
        }else {
            res = cadMayor(lista, tamLista, cuentaMinusculas(lista.get(pos)), pos-1);
        }
    }

    return res;
}


//NO HACE FALTA PASARLO A RECURSIVO FINAL, DEJARLO EN ITERATIVO
//Metodo para contar el numero de minúsculas de cada elemento (cadena) de List<String>l
 public static int cuentaMinusculas(String cadena) {
     Integer i = cadena.length()-1;
     int cont = 0;

     while(i >= 0) {
         char a = cadena.charAt(i);
         if(Character.isLowerCase(a)) {
             cont++;
         }
         i--;
     }
     return cont;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo un par de inconvenientes en el código que tienes.

Primero:

```
System.out.println("La cadena con mayor numero de minusculas es: " +cadMayor(lista, lista.size(), cuentaMinusculas(lista.get(lista.size())), lista.size()-1 ));
```

La linea de código de arriba donde haces el `lista.get(lista.size())` esta mal, por que `get` espera un indice dentro del rango del array entre 0 a size - 1. Por lo que hay muchas probabilidades de que los otros `lista.get` también estén fallando con `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Segundo:
Dentro de la función `cadMayor` miremos la siguiente linea.

```
comparador = lista.get(pos).compareTo(cadMayor(lista, tamLista, cuentaMinusculas(lista.get(pos)), pos-1));
```

Si te fijas estas comparando que cadenas es mayor, en vez de comparar que cadena tiene un numero mayor de minúsculas.

Tercero: el paramtro `int cuentaMinusculas` de la funcion `cadMayor` nunca lo utilizas.

***Prueba con esto y adaptalo a lo que necesitas:***

```
// esta va en el main
System.out.println("La cadena con mayor numero de minusculas es: " + cadMayor(lista, lista.size()-1, ""));

//aca te dejo la funcion
public static String cadMayor(List<String>lista, int pos, String strMayor) {
    //- la funcion no valida si la lista es nula,
    //no valida si solo tiene un item y ese item esta en mayuscula cerrada.
    //- lo mejor es que crees otra funcion que envuelva a la primera,
    //de este modo la funcion que expones al cliente no nesecita parsarle el strMayor

    String res = "";

    if(lista.size() == 1) {
        res = lista.get(pos);
    } else if(pos <= -1) {
        res = strMayor;
    } else {
        if(cuentaMinusculas(strMayor) > cuentaMinusculas(lista.get(pos))) {
            res = cadMayor(lista, pos-1, strMayor);
        } else {
            res = cadMayor(lista, pos-1, lista.get(pos));
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```